# deserialize database object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a statistic model

```
class Statistic < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize  :value
end
```

The model contains a value attribute containing a Goals object. I want to deserialize the goals object

when I do

```
goals = Statistic.all
goals.each do |goal|
  test = goal.value      
end
```

I get an error

```
value was supposed to be a Goals, but was a String
```

In the debugger I see that goal.value is of type String and contains the goal data

```
--- !ruby/object:Goals \ngoals: {}\n\ngoals_against: 1\ngoals_for: 0\nversion: 1\n
```

When I add `serialize  :value, Goals` I get following error when deserialzing

```
ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch in ClubsController#new

value was supposed to be a Goals, but was a String
```

The Goals class

```
class Goals
  attr_accessor :goals
  attr_accessor :goals_for
  attr_accessor :goals_against
  attr_accessor :goals_own
  attr_accessor :penalty_for
  attr_accessor :penalty_against 

  def initialize(goals = nil, goals_against = nil, goals_own = nil, penalty_for = nil, penalty_against = nil)
    @version = 1 
    if goals.nil?   
      @goals = {}
    else
      @goals = goals    
    end    
    @goals_against = goals_against.to_i     
    @goals_own = goals_own.to_i unless goals_own.nil?
    unless penalty_for.nil? 
      @penalty_for = penalty_for.to_i
      @penalty_against = penalty_against.to_i
    end
    set_goals_for()
  end

  private
  def set_goals_for    
    @goals_for = 0
    @goals.each_value {|value|  @goals_for += value.to_i }
    @goals_for += @goals_own unless @goals_own.nil?
  end
end
```

Someone knows how I can make rails know that its an goals object and not a string?

Thanks

Comment: can you copy-paste your Goal class? can you also try to setup default value for "value" db column as empty object "--- []"

Comment: how do I add that empty object? I 'm using sqlite for development

Comment: I see your Goals class for now. the serialization will not work until you provide **load** and **dump** methods for Goals class

Comment: **dump** and **load** are the mandatory methods **serialze** use. it doesn't relate any specific any Rails version. you can see the Array, Hash by ActiveSupport already have such methods. Serialization by YAML, Marshal, JSON require the dump/load methods.

Comment: Isn't this **dump** and **load** a feature of rails 3.1? I'm using rail 3.0

Comment: do you have an example on how to implement this somewhere? This deserialization use to work in the past without dump/load. Do you know why?

Comment: @mikhailov let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1576/discussion-between-tarscher-and-mikhailov)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of my experience with serialization problems comes from Rails 1 era, but I recall two usual reasons of serialization failures:

- silently ignored exceptions
- class reloading

Looking at the file `./activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb` (tag v3.0.7 from git) I see that there is a 'rescue' clause:

```
def object_from_yaml(string)
  return string unless string.is_a?(String) && string =~ /^---/
  YAML::load(string) rescue string
end
```

You may try to investigate what exception is thrown by `YAML::load`. I usually change this method into something like this:

```
  begin
    YAML::load(string)
  rescue => e
    Rails.logger.warn "YAML exception (ignored): #{e.inspect}"
    string
  end
```

About the class reloading, is your problem also visible in test mode? I was registering my classes in YAML, and noticed that the class definition was gone in each second request, since the class object was recreated, and the registered one was taken away from the class chains. I don't think this is your problem, but I am signalling it anyway - maybe this will be helpful?

Comment: In 3.0.7 the method 'object_from_yaml' is the same as in 3.0.0. But I saw you already found the problem to be the SQLite escaping, right?